# trying to install an apk file on android emulator getting error missing shared library

Tags: android

hi when I am trying to install an apk file it is saying that missing shared library, it is not Google maps apk, it is an android package for testing an application. And I want it to test on an emulator, so what should I do now to install my app on emulator..
required help.

```
H:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\platform-tools>adb install test_UAT_v2.0.8.apk
842 KB/s (7259037 bytes in 8.413s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/test_UAT_v2.0.8.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]
```